# Check if a video on YouTube is available from the URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, youtube, youtube-api, availability

How can I check if a YouTube video is available or unavailable for any reason from the URL or video id by using JavaScript in an html website

for example:

this link goes to a video that is available 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aY1Z15vTw0

this link goes to a video that is not available
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMbz0444444

I want to make it so it does something different depending on whether the video from the link is available or not

if youtube link is available:
do something

else:
do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and check on `uploadStatus`.

Possible [statuses](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) are:

- deleted
- failed
- processed
- rejected
- uploaded

Comment: Then you have a different problem. I recommend brushing up on basic programming first.